# How to find sum and count per column order in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an email exchange data frame that looks like below:

```
sender receiver words 
a        b       10
a        c       5
a        c       15
b        a       50
b        a       30
```

I'd like to get to the below dataframe. `Words_xy` indicates the number of words sent from sender to receiver, while `words_yx` is the number of words sent from receiver to sender. `Email_xy` is the total number of messages (count) sent from sender to receiver, and the reverse is true for `email_yx`.

```
x-y      y-x   words_xy  words_yx   email_xy   email_yx
ab       ba       10      (50+30)      1         2
ac       ca     (5+15)      0          2         0
```

I was able to get the x-y combination by first merging `sender, receiver` to `x-y` using `df['x-y']=df['sender']+df['receiver']`. Then I apply below code to obtain words_xy and email_xy:

```
df['email_xy'] = df.groupby('sender-receiver')['sender-receiver'].transform('count')
df['words_xy']=df.groupby(['sender-receiver','email_xy'], as_index=False)['words'].sum()
```

How do I obtain the reverse for y-x and append it to the data frame? Perhaps there is a better way than using Pandas to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be something like:

[`Groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) to get the sum and counts

```
new_df = (
    df
        .groupby(['sender', 'receiver'], as_index=False)
        .agg(words=('words', 'sum'), email=('words', 'count'))
)
```

```
  sender receiver  words  email
0      a        b     10      1
1      a        c     20      2
2      b        a     80      2
```

Do a self-join ([`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge))with self and a self with sender and receiver columns swapped to get relationships:

```
new_df = (
    new_df
        .merge(new_df.rename(columns={'sender': 'receiver',
                                      'receiver': 'sender'}),
               on=['sender', 'receiver'],
               suffixes=('_xy', '_yx'),
               how='left')
        .fillna(0)
        .convert_dtypes()
)
```

```
  sender receiver  words_xy  email_xy  words_yx  email_yx
0      a        b        10         1        80         2
1      a        c        20         2         0         0
2      b        a        80         2        10         1
```

Then add new columns:

```
new_df['x-y'] = new_df['sender'] + new_df['receiver']
new_df['y-x'] = new_df['receiver'] + new_df['sender']
```

```
  sender receiver  words_xy  email_xy  words_yx  email_yx x-y y-x
0      a        b        10         1        80         2  ab  ba
1      a        c        20         2         0         0  ac  ca
2      b        a        80         2        10         1  ba  ab
```

Get rid of duplicates: lots of ways to do this, but I went with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-series-drop-duplicates) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html#pandas-series-unstack):

```
new_df = (
    new_df.drop(columns=['sender', 'receiver'])
        .set_index(['words_xy', 'words_yx', 'email_xy', 'email_yx'])
        .stack()
        .drop_duplicates()
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
)
```

```
   words_xy  words_yx  email_xy  email_yx x-y y-x
0        10        80         1         2  ab  ba
1        20         0         2         0  ac  ca
```

Lastly re-order the columns:

```
new_df = new_df[['x-y', 'y-x', 'words_xy', 'words_yx', 'email_xy', 'email_yx']]
```

```
  x-y y-x  words_xy  words_yx  email_xy  email_yx
0  ab  ba        10        80         1         2
1  ac  ca        20         0         2         0
```

Comment: Thank you @Nk03 =)